# Prevent FOUC in context of a Kentico 10 website

Tags: zurb-foundation, kentico

Zurb Foundation recommends [adding class="no-js" to the page html tag](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/installation.html#html-starter-template) to prevent against Flash of Unstyled Content (FOUC).

We are using Kentico CMS. I'm looking for the "Kentico way" of adding a class to the `html` element tag in the master page. We are using the CMS portal engine.

What we're going for 
`<html class="no-js"`

Willing to fall back into ASP.NET if there's not a more approachable way using Kentico macros or its API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your master page portal template you can add some code like this to make that modification:

```
<script runat="server">
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (CurrentDocument != null)
    {          
        CMS.UIControls.ContentPage page= this.Page as CMS.UIControls.ContentPage;
        if (page != null)
        {
            page.XmlNamespace += " class='no-js'";
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

You can also modify the \CMSPages\PortalTemplate.aspx page as well but that is not supported or recommended by Kentico as it typically breaks the upgrade path.

Comment: Thanks @Brenden, I was concerned about the upgrade path when posting this question - thanks for noting that aspect of it.

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way I know of is to modify `CMSPages\PortalTemplate.aspx` to add your class in there.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="CMSPages_PortalTemplate" ValidateRequest="false" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" EnableEventValidation="false" Codebehind="PortalTemplate.aspx.cs" %>

<%=DocType%>
<html <%=XHtmlNameSpace%> <%=XmlNamespace%> class="no-js">
<head id="head" runat="server" enableviewstate="false">
...
```

Comment: My one concern is breaking the upgrade path, although this is a minor change to make sure is noted for when an upgrade occurs. Thank you.

Comment: Fair point, @JohnK. There is a definite need to make notes of stuff like this in the solution documentation. 

Answer (score 1):

The “no-js” is à default value. If, indeed, your browser DOES SUPPORT JavaScript, the “no-is" class will be stripped by the Modernizr engine.

Modernizr is a JavaScript library and it will check the browser capabilities and update the html class="” mention.

For example, if your browser supports the flexbox technology, the flexbox class will be added to the html class list. Otherwise, no-flexbox class will be added.

Later, when using CSS framework (Bootstrap or Foundation), some strategies could be used to emulate a missing feature.